# How to create duplicate product programmatically in magento2.4.6?

Tags: magento2, product, programmatically, magento2.4.6

I want to create a duplicate product using the product id programmatically. I have tried many solutions but have not had success.
How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Let's create a class that would handle this:

```
namespace .....

class ProductClone
{
    private \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Copier $copier;
    private \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $repository;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Copier $copier,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $repository
    ) {
        $this->copier = $copier;
        $this->repository = $repository;
    }

    public function duplicate(int $productId): \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface
    {
         $product = $this->repository->getById($productId);
         return $this->copier->copy($product);
    }
}
```

Now you just need to include this class as a dependency in your custom logic and call the `duplicate` method with your product id as a parameter.

Watch out for typos in the code above, I didn't test it.

Answer (score 0):

Copying products programmatically in Magento 2 can be achieved using the native approach, which utilizes Magento's built-in functionality in the Admin panel for copying products. To do this, you can take advantage of the `Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Duplicate` controller along with the `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\ProductCopier` class, which simplifies the process for you.

Below is an example of how you can implement the product duplication:

```php
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Copier $productCopier */
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository */
$product = $productRepository->get('SKU');
$duplicatedProduct = $productCopier->copy($product);
```

In the code above, we use the `ProductRepositoryInterface` to load the product with the specified SKU you want to duplicate. Then, we pass that product instance to the ProductCopier to create a new duplicated product.